# Background Gradient and Filter in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Why the following code doesn't work in IE?

**Gradient code doesn't work in IE**

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0B282F, white);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#0B282F, white);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#0B282F, white);
background: linear-gradient(#0B282F, white);
```

**Filter doesnt work in IE.**

```
filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 100px #fff);;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 100px #fff);
filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 100px #fff);
-o-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 100px #fff);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference : http://caniuse.com/#search=filter and http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient

IE 9,8 doesn't support gradients.
IE 11,9,8 doesn't support filter property.
In EDGE it needs to be enabled under "Enable CSS filter property" flag.

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/  Try with following example . Add this property

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

Comment: I mean with the `drop-shadow`.. it worked fine in chrome and mozilla.. but doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Why don't you use box-shadow? It support IE 11 and 9.

Comment: `drop-shadow` has different behavior compare to `box-shadow`.. drop-shadow takes the shape of an image while box-shadow creates a border like shadow...

Comment: Ok. drop-shadow won't work on IE because it's a filter property which IE doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

try this for gradient color in IE  may it helps you

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0b282f', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```